# Merging two data frames in a loop but TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' after first loop

Tags: python, pandas, nlp

I am trying to merge a two data frames that has where one df_1 has dataset information and df_2 is in a loop that has the nlp text in a list.

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'text':['A','B','C'],'other_info':['12','24','34'],'nlp_text':[[('together', 'RB'),('subsidiary', 'NN')],np.NaN,np.NaN]}.reset_index()

df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'text':'B','nlp_text':[('produce', 'NN'), ('sell', 'VBP')]},index=[0])
```

I used the merge the first nlp_text using

```
df_1 = pd.merge(df_1,df_2, how='outer').groupby('text').first().reset_index()
```

After the first loop I get the error. In the loop i will be merging df_2 over and over again. df_1 is the result after first merge

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: There are some mistakes on df_1 and df_2 definitions above.  What is ```tic``` on df_2 ? If it is a list such as in df_1 , thecode should work. However you will have two columns with the name ```npl_text``` in them, one from df_1 and another from df_2...
```

Comment: @Bruck1701 i changed the tic, it should be 'B' because i want to merge B  in df_1 with B in df_2. if i  `df_1 = pd.merge(df_1,df_2 on='text,how = 'outer')` it works but like u say it will create a new colunm and that is something that i don't want. I want the merge to be in the original npl_text colunm

Answer (score 0):

you still have some problems in df_1.

1. a dictionary has no attribute reset_index
2. did you see `C'`? in `'text':['A','B',C']`

[image: output]

if this is the output you need. this is the code:

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'text':['A','B','C'],'other_info':['12','24','34'],'nlp_text':[['together', 'RB'],['subsidiary', 'NN'],[np.NaN,np.NaN]]})

df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'text':'B','nlp-text':[['produce', 'NN'], ['sell', 'VBP']]},index=[0, 1])
```

3. are you sure you want nlp-text and nlp_text or is it a typo?

Comment: @Uzhan sorry my bad it is a typo, i want to merge df_2 'B' data into df_1. Inside the nlp_text is not a dictionary it is actually a Lists of Tuples.